# UbuntuOne contact synching for Thunderbird?

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird, contacts

Is it possible to sync UbuntuOne contacts with Thunderbird's address book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 11.10 (a year and a half after you asked) the answer is a resounding "yes." At this stage integration works well.

Comment: I'll have to check it out, but I don't know if it's necessary for me anymore.  I have since started syncing my contacts through gmail with an extension, but it's nice to see Ubuntu making progress.

Comment: It works?  If you have any steps or instructions for doing it, please let us know.  (I can't find any way to do it.)

Answer (score 4):

Michael is correct. Thunderbird doesn't integrate with CouchDB (yet :) so the only way to get it to sync with the Ubuntu One cloud is through our mobile phone contacts sync service since Funambol (our technology partner) has developed an add-on for that application. They also have add-ons for MS Outlook and the Mac Address Book applications.

Currently their add-on does not support Thunderbird 3 (so jumpnett is correct) but they're working on supporting that version of the application.

Thanks!

Comment: As of ~Nov '11 / Thunderbird does integrate with Couch DB. I'm on Version 9.0, Ubuntu 11.10 and integration is definitely in place.

Answer (score 3):

It is supported, but not quite as elegantly as Evolution syncing.  Here's the step-by-step:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Contacts#Sync%20Thunderbird%20contacts

Basically, you must tell Ubuntu One you have a mobile phone (you can fake it) and then install the mobile phone syncing plugin for Thunderbird and point it at Ubuntu One.

Comment: The Funambol Add-on mentioned in the link isn't compatible with Thunderbird 3.1.2.

Comment: As of Nov 2011, this answer was no longer accurate. Ubuntu One discontinued mobile support (temporarily, they swear) and Thunderbird 9 integrates with CouchDB.